# Regexp: Check for digits and whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regexp to make sure my string contains 5 digits. It works perfect, however, I also need to allow whitespaces: 123 45 and 12345 need to pass the test.

```
string.match(/^\d{5}$/g);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply remove any whitespace and then try to match the rest:

```
string.replace(/\s/g, "").match(/^\d{5}$/g)
```